# Broken Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing

Our project is in agile environment where requirements keep changing every sprint. The annoying part is the unit tests keep failing due to the requirement change. And now it takes longer to fix and maintain them.

Do you have any suggestions in general, what is the better approach for this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are the tests failing? Is it because they are testing the old requirements?  Wouldn't that be a good thing if those are failing?

Comment: If the requirements change, then the tests need to change, then the code needs to change so that the tests pass.

Comment: Would you prefer it if you didn't know what parts were broken?

Comment: Thanks, guys. Your comments are all valid. It's just frustrating and time-consuming to keep modifying tests, especially recreating all the mocking objects again.

Comment: I would say that you should be testing individual objects behaviour, even if the requirements change it shpuld generally just mean changing the objects you use, if you are regularly breaking everything to make a change you should look at the design and also look at what you are testing

Comment: re "especially recreating all the mocking objects again", maybe there is a process improvement for mocking that could help ease the refactor burden, eg, an auto mocking library or such?  I use Moq and Structuremap's AutoMocker, but not sure what lang or framework you are using here.  It is important to look for ways to reduce test friction, if it becomes too much of a chore, it's less likely to be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue, and is related to how committed you are to maintaining your unit tests.

You mention your tests break when requirements change, so I'm assuming this means you update code to meet the changing requirements, but you're not updating your tests at the same time.

A development approach fully committed to the benefits of repeatable unit tests would always update the unit test code at the same time code changes are made. If you don't, how do you re-test the code changes, or how can you prove the code changes work?

If you're not committed to maintaining unit tests at the same time as code changes, then you might as well embrace that fact and throw them away as soon as the code changes, because at that point, as you're finding out, the tests become useless.

It's a common problem and one that many projects struggle with. Are tests written one time to test code when initially written, but after that point are discarded, or are they always maintained at the same time when code changes are made? Sure, it adds more effort to maintain the tests, but then you benefit longer term from having a suite of repeatable tests that you can run at any time to test that your code is working as expected, before and after any code changes.